# mongo is not able to reach from Docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am a newbie to docker.

I am trying to run go app with MongoDB + docker and using docker-compose to have two containers(go and mongo)

I am seeing error `no reachable servers` while connecting to mongo via go app, although mongo server is running on 0.0.0.0:27010(after seeing from 
`docker ps`)

but when I use 0.0.0.0 as connection IP address, it gives an error in connection. I am sure its IP problem, but do not know how can I fix this?

Comment: could you provide `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: in typical cases you need to use container names instead of IP adresses

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is not an IP address but a wildcard used in mongodb config to make mongod listening on all IPv4 interfaces: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp

Comment: I see `host=a1f0680f8458` in logs, How can i bind it to  static?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! service name was the hostname, but docker-compose has to be version - "3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look on [links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) of docker-compose

Example:

```
services:
  your-app-container:
    links:
      - mongodb

    mongodb:
     image: mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

The `port` in which the mongo container is running should be published to the host, so that the Golang app container can access it.

```
docker run --publish 27010:27010  mongo
```

Comment: I see `host=a1f0680f8458` in logs, How can i bind it to  static?