# Mongo Socket Exception: hostname or service unknown while running in a docker container

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, socketexception

i have been trying to a mongo server, which i was able to from an IDE. But when i dockerize the whole application and run in a docker. i am facing a mongosocket exception saying the host name or the service is unkown.

i understand that if we want to connect to local mongo server running in local host to our application. we need to run two containers one for mongodb and other for our application. and we need to link both the containers. But should we run two containers for connecting to a non-local mongo sever ? how is the connection established in this case ?

please explain!
thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62229008/how-to-allow-all-hosts-to-a-replica-set-in-mongodb/62233373#62233373 for network connectivity requirements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongo is not able to reach from Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280589/mongo-is-not-able-to-reach-from-docker-container)